# C++ std::memory_order_relaxed and skip/stop flag

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdatomic, memory-barriers

Is it ok to use `std::memory_order_relaxed` for skip flag, like in `iterate`:

```
    constexpr static const std::size_t capacity = 128; 
    std::atomic<bool> aliveness[capacity];
    T data[capacity];     // immutable/atomic/etc.

    template<class Closure>
    void iterate(Closure&& closure){
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i<capacity; i++){
            if (!aliveness[i].load(std::memory_order_relaxed)) continue;                    
            closure( data[i] );
        }
    }

    void erase(std::size_t index){
        aliveness[index].store(false, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }
```

Or I should use release/acquire, instead?

`aliveness[i]` may become "alive" again.

`iterate` and `erase` called from multiple threads simuteniously. Consider `data` immutable/atomic/synchronized under some other external lock.

Comment: What do you mean "is it ok"?

Comment: Why is `size` atomic, and why are you re-reading it (with a default seq_cst load) every loop iteration of the `for` loop?

Comment: @PeterCordes updated to simpler case.

Comment: By asking "is it ok", I mean - if in one thread do `erase`, does another thread which `iterate` will see that flag becomes false; and how soon. Is it possible that we call `erase` in one thread, but another thread did not saw that flag changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assumption: other thread(s) can be running `iterate()` at any time while you're using `erase`.  (An early version of the question didn't specify immutable.  This answer is still relevant if the locking (or lack thereof) for updating `data[i]` isn't ordered wrt. writes to `alive[i]`.)

If data is truly immutable, then `mo_relaxed` is definitely fine, unless you need the global visibility of those stores to be ordered with respect to something *else* the thread is doing.  `mo_relaxed` stores will always eventually become visible to other threads (and on current CPUs, will do so very quickly).

---

If you're going to modify the non-atomic `data[i]` while `alive[i]` is false, you need to make sure other threads aren't using its value while it's being modified.  That would be UB in C++, and an actual correctness problem on real hardware depending on `T` and `closure`.

Acquire semantics will work for `iterate`.  Access to `data[i]` logically happens after `alive[i]`, because the one-way barrier is in the correct direction.  [The acquire-load won't reorder with later loads or stores, only earlier ones](http://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/).

But the store in `erase` is a problem.  It needs to be globally visible before any modification of `data[i]`.  But release-stores are allowed to reorder with later stores.  What you need is [a release *fence* to block reordering of stores in both directions](http://preshing.com/20131125/acquire-and-release-fences-dont-work-the-way-youd-expect/).

```
void erase(std::size_t index){
    aliveness[index].store(false, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);
  // or don't do that, this probably wouldn't be enough synchronization
  // and whatever you do that syncs the data might make this unnecessary.
}
```

If `T` was an atomic type, a release-store to `data[i]` would do the trick.  But don't do that; that will suck if `T` is too large to be lock-free atomic.

(**Update: I'm not sure this is fully valid**.  The ISO C++ memory ordering rules are defined in terms of synchronizes-with / happens-before, and what values a given load is allowed to see.  Not in terms of reordering per-se between atomic and non-atomic operations.

Also, this is like what you'd do for a SeqLock, but that also depends on data-race UB for reads.  If another thread is going to read `data[i]`, if it checks `alive[i]` then reads, there's a TOCTOU race: our write to `alive` could happen after that read, and then our write to `data[i]` could happen simultaneously with another thread reading.
**So this is probably insufficient to erase / modify / un-erase an element**, even on a strongly-ordered non-weird machine like x86.)

---

On some implementations, a seq-cst store would also work, but I think only as an implementation detail.  It usually results in a store + a full-barrier asm instruction.  (e.g. x86 MFENCE).  So it works only because compilers implement seq-cst stores as store + `thread_fence(seq_cst)`.  And that's not the case on AArch64 where STLR is just a release operation; only the interaction with LDAR gives SC-DRF.  (seq_cst for data-race-free programs).

---

Note that `iterate` isn't safe if `closure` modifies `data[]`, unless only one thread can call it at a time.  In which case, what's the point of this?  So probably you should use

```
void iterate(Closure&& closure) const
{ ... }
```

so `iterate` only works on `const` objects of your container.

Comment: Consider `data` immutable/atomic. Sorry for this inaccuracy. The question is rather about `aliveness` visibility/propagation between threads (start to understand this just now). Is changes to it becomes immideatley visible to all threads, or it can be false-readed with previous value. Like: we set it to `false` in Thread1, but Thread2 read previous `true` value.

Comment: @tower: Stores to `aliveness[i]` will eventually become visible to loads in all other threads.  (Usually extremely quickly, like only the length of the store buffer in the producer CPU + size of the out-of-order window for doing read early in the consumer CPUs).  But yes, out-of-order execution of loads can lead to different consumers seeing different values.  You have to be careful how you define "simultaneous" because of out-of-order execution.  If there isn't some *other* way these threads are interacting, it's a meaningless question because there's no synchronization between them.

Comment: so, in as-is example - it is rather opportunistic/speculative erase:), but if I switch to acquire - release semantic it will free from false readings?

Comment: @tower120: No, if you're not modifying `data[i]` then it makes no sense to call it "false".  There's simply no ordering between the threads.  It's not "wrong" to let `iterate` use a `data` value loaded before the corresponding `alive` value, because the C++ standard does encourage implementations to make relaxed stores visible to other threads quickly.  You can assume that it's not visible much sooner; it will just potentially make `iterate` run slower to make sure it doesn't use a `data` value loaded early.

Comment: I guess, you're right about letting iterate one or two extra elements...